# An elementary question about cardinal arithmetic 2

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I put this one in other question that I had. But I'm not sure if that is permitted here. So, better open other question though is related to the last one.

**Claim 1:** If $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets, the set of all the functions from $X$ to $Y$ is finite.

*Proof:* Let $\varphi (n)$ be "the set of all the functions from a finite set of size $n$ to a finite set $Y$ is always finite".

$$S = \left\{\, n \in \omega: \varphi (n)\, \right\}$$

For $n = 0$. Clearly  $0 \in S$, because the set of all the functions from the empty set to a finite set $Y$ contain only one element (the empty function).

Suppose $n \in S $, $X$ has size $n^{+} $ and $Y$ is finite. We want to show that $Y^{X}$ is finite. As $X$ has size $n^{+}$, there exist a bijection $f \colon X\rightarrow n^{+} =n \cup \left\{n \right\}$. Suppose $z\in X $ and it is sent to $ n \in n^{+}$, $ f(z) = n$. Then $f$ restricts to a bijection from $X - \left\{ z \right\}$ to $n$. And by our inductive hypothesis the set $Y^{X - \left\{ z \right\}}$ is finite.

For $Y^{\left\{ z \right\}}$ each function is determined by which $Y$ element is chosen as $ h(z) = y_{z}$. We can define a bijection $ \theta_{y}\colon Y \rightarrow Y^{\left\{ z \right\}}$, $i\mapsto$  "function $f$ such that $f(z) =i$". Hence, $Y \sim Y^{\left\{ z \right\}}$ and both are finite. And as the cartesian of two finite set is finite, $Y^{X - \left\{ z \right\}} \times Y^{\left\{ z \right\}}$ is finite.

If $Y^{X - \left\{ z \right\}} \times Y^{\left\{ z \right\}} \sim Y^{X}$ the set  is finite and $n^{+} \in S$.

**Claim 2:** There exist a bijection from $ Y^{X}$ to $Y^{X - \left\{ z \right\}} \times Y^{\left\{ z \right\}}$.

*Proof:* Let

$$ \theta = \left\{\, \langle \left.f\right|_ {X-\left\{ z \right\}},\left.f\right|_\left\{ z \right\} \rangle : f\in Y^{X}\, \right\}$$

Functional: Let $f \in Y^{X}$, then $ \theta (f) = \langle \left.f\right|_ {X-\left\{ z \right\}},\left.f\right|_\left\{ z \right\} \rangle $ by extensionality is unique.

Injectivity: Let $f,g \in Y^{X}$ and $f \not= g$ that means $\exists x\in X\colon f(x) \not = g(x)$.

If $ x\in {X - \left\{ z \right\}}$ then $\left.f\right|_ {X-\left\{ z \right\}} \not = \left.g\right|_ {X-\left\{ z \right\}}$. And if $ x\in \left\{ z \right\}$, i.e. $x = z$, then $\left.f\right|_\left\{ z \right\} \not = \left.g\right|_\left\{ z \right\}$. In either case $ \theta (f) \not= \theta(g)$.

Surjectivity: $\langle a,b \rangle \in \,Y^{X - \left\{ z \right\}} \times Y^{\left\{ z \right\}} \leftrightarrow a \in Y^{X - \left\{ z \right\}} \wedge b \in Y^{\left\{ z \right\}} $.

Let $a_{b} \colon X \rightarrow Y,\; i \mapsto \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         a(i) & \mbox{if $\, i\in  X - \left\{ z \right\}$}\\
        b(i) & \mbox{if $\,i = z $}\end{array} \right. $

$ a_{b} $ is the extension of $a$, therefore we have: $a_{b} \in Y^{X}$.

Do you think my attempt is correct?

After that in other exercise I want to show that if X and Y be finite sets. Then, $ \# \left( Y^{X} \right ) = \#Y^{\#X}$. But I have not worked in the exercise yet :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $\theta$ in the proof of **Claim 2** isn’t right: you want

$$\theta=\left\{\Big\langle f,\big\langle f\upharpoonright(X\setminus\{z\}),f\upharpoonright\{z\}\big\rangle\Big\rangle:f\in{}^XY\right\}\;,$$

so that it really is a function from ${}^XY$ to ${}^{X\setminus\{z\}}Y\times{}^{\{z\}}Y$. (I prefer the notation ${}^AB$ for the set of functions from $A$ to $B$.) With your $\theta$, the expression $\theta(f)$ does not make sense.

Apart from that small error, your proof is fine, though you did not really need ${}^{\{z\}}Y$: you could have let

$$\theta=\left\{\Big\langle f,\big\langle f\upharpoonright(X\setminus\{z\}),f(z)\big\rangle\Big\rangle:f\in{}^XY\right\}$$

and shown that $\theta$ was a bijection between ${}^XY$ and ${}^{X\setminus\{z\}}Y\times Y$.

For the other exercise, make use of bijections $h:X\to\#X$ and $k:Y\to\#Y$.

Comment: Thanks. One question: I've seen both notation in different books and different notes (the notation of the set of all the functions from one set to another) but there exist some advantage from using one of them. I explain me, the book uses the same that I put it above, but says that can be source of confusion, however I cannot figure out where is the confusion.

Comment: @Jose: You’re welcome. The possible confusion arises mostly when the sets are (infinite) cardinal numbers, say $\kappa$ and $\lambda$. Then $\kappa^\lambda$ can be either the set of functions from $\lambda$ to $\kappa$ or the cardinal number that is the cardinality of that set of functions. I prefer to use ${}^\lambda\kappa$ for the set of functions and $\kappa^\lambda$ for the cardinal exponentiation.